# disable dates in vue date picker

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I need to disable some dates. My attempt is as below.

```
<v-date-picker
        v-model="dates3"
        :max-date="today">
</v-date-picker>

data() {
  return {
    today: '2021-06-04',
    dates3: '2021-06-02'
  }
}
```

But it will not disable all the dates after 2021-06-04. Where I was get wrong and how can I fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Took Docs as reference its just `max` not `max-date`

```
<v-date-picker
    v-model="date3"
    max="today"
/>
```

Should solve it :)